# How long is a day in GTA V in real time?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

How long is a Grand Theft Auto 5 day in real time?

Comment: Just following advice on "It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions": http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ for anyone that's wondering.

Comment: Some missions start at certain times of day or have to be completed between certain hours. Sometimes it's just useful to know how long you've got or how long you need to wait in real time.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A full day in GTA 5 takes **48 minutes** real time.

One hour takes 2 minutes.

Game time stops when pausing, will automatically advance when starting some missions and using a bed to save will advance game time by 6 hours (Michael), 8 hours (Franklin) or 12 hours (Trevor).

Note: Game time does not stop when pausing in GTA Online.

Comment: +1 I always assumed 1 real second is equivalent to 1 in-game minute. I guess 2:1 makes more sense.

Comment: You may want to edit this and add info for online time. If its the same, pausing the game won't change it. This matters when it comes to paying utility bills on your homes etc. Those bills come out 'daily.'

Comment: @leigero that isn't what is being asked here. They are asking **How long is a day in GTAV in real time?** not **How long is a day in GTA Online in real time?** These are two completely different questions.

Comment: @Popeye True at the time, but it's probably more relevant now to GTA Online, especially for those wondering how long it will take to "survive a day with a bounty". No harm in adding a note about the game not pausing time.

Comment: I can't confirm this myself, but apparently characters have different sleep times: http://gtaforums.com/topic/628291-trevor-sleeps-for-12-hours-not-6/.  There is also the fact that you can set how many hours a night your character sleeps for creating your online character, not sure if that actually applies or does anything though as I've never slept online.

Comment: @turbo I can confirm the different sleep times, just tested them. Thanks for the heads up.