# Assasination Missions. How to invest money and make more money?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I have finished the main story and all my main characters ended up making close to 31 Million apiece from the Big one. I only finished one Assassination mission so far which was the Hotel assassination, but i didn't play others because people advised me to reserve the Assassination missions to the end of the game.

This is all i know currently that these assassination missions end up killing some company's CEO and trick is to invest on their opposite number.

I want to know what others used to make money from these missions like if i should invest all my money on opposite company's stock from all the characters and play the mission and another question being once i complete the mission when is a good time to sell the stocks again?

Comment: Lester usually hints towards where to make your investments.   I have had it go both ways.

Comment: Your lucky, I heard you can make over 500m from doing this smart investing, I didn't think of this or read about this until I passed the game as I wanted a blind run through the game. I might replay it. Please tell me how much money you make from this all together from your 31m

Comment: i see mine as a different question. I am asking how much money to invest and whats the prime time to sell them.

Comment: why would you invest less than you have? the more you invest, the more you gain.

Comment: @Wojtek'Charkz'Hordyniec i will keep you posted about how much i make from these.

Comment: You end up with ~1.4b per character I think if you do all of them correctly after the big heist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a handful of missions that allow you to make a fortune. Following the guide below, and save before each investment just incase something backfires.

- **The Hotel Assassination**: Invest in Betapharmasuticals before the
  mission and cash out afterward.
- **The Redwood Cigarette Assassination**: Invest in Debonaire
  Cigarettes before the mission. After the mission, sell all of your
  share of Debonaire when it reaches maximum profit (around 80%).

  - Then invest in Redwood. Save your game 8 times to pass    (48 hours)
    for Redwood shares to spike to 300%.
- **The Vice Assassination**: Invest in Fruit before the mission and
  sell    afterwards.
- **The Bus Assassination**: Invest in Vapid after you complete    the
  mission and cash out afterwards.
- **The Construction Assassination**:    Invest in Gold Coast Development
  before the mission and sell    afterwards.

Comment: so my question do i invest all my money on it completely? and 80% is the max it can go to?

Comment: Sorry, i'll edit into the question. Yes invest 100% if you follow this exactly you should be grand. Make saves before the mission each time just in case something back fires.

Comment: sleeping 8 times only passes 48 hours as Michael(see http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/131781/how-long-is-a-day-in-gta-v-in-real-time/131782#comment187045_131782), and weekends don't count on the stock market so be wary of this when you are waiting for your investments to grow

Comment: wow investing in redwood was gold. i am on 220 million already with 3 assassinations to go.

Comment: i eventually ended up making 1.3 Billion across all characters at end of all assasinations