# How long after an assassination does it take for effected shares to hit max value?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I'm replaying GTA5 and trying to get as much money as possible this time around. So my plan is to use up all my cash on the assassination targets rivals and then sell up after completing the hit.

However, I can't find any advice on *when* to sell up. I don't want to sell too early and lose out on profit, but I don't want to sell too late once prices have started to fall.

[This post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/137425/assasination-missions-how-to-invest-money-and-make-more-money/137428#137428) says 48hrs, but is specifically for the Redwood hit and says nothing for the others.

How long does it take for shares to peak, and how long do they stay there before plunging back to normal?